Most efficient method to get subset of SQL table based on ID
I have tables with 50-70 million rows. Each row represents an object with a unique ID number. A table is for a specific year, say 2015. I need to return the IDs contained in the 2015 table that are contained in subsequent year tables.
First I query the initial year, 2015, and then I use R to iterate over the years and retrieve rows with IDs in the previous table.
query <- glue::glue(sprintf(
            "SELECT id, col_1, col_2
             FROM schema.data_{year}
             WHERE schema.data_{year}.id in ('%s')",
         toString(prev_ids)), year=year)
res <- dbGetQuery(con, query)

For a small sample this is fine, but gets increasingly slow as n increases.
I am fairly new to SQL so I am wondering, how should I approach this?

"as n increases" - what "n"? Do you mean that number of values contained within the %s parameter?

You are making a huge design mistake. Put them all in one big table with a year column and the right indexing.

@Charlieface I would do this, but it is not my server. I do not have permission to edit or create new tables.

@AdrianMaxwell I meant the total sample size. My code is fine when I randomly sample 0.01% of the rows, but a larger sample becomes slower and slower. But then yes, that also means the number of values in %s.

Don't iterate client side, just do it all in the server.
You have a huge design flaw, by keeping these in separate tables. You can hack it with a CTE or derived table that unions it all together:
SELECT id, col_1, col_2
FROM schema.data_2015 d
WHERE d.id in (
    SELECT d2.id FROM schema.data_2016 d2
    UNION ALL
    SELECT d2.id FROM schema.data_2017 d2
    UNION ALL
    SELECT d2.id FROM schema.data_2018 d2
    UNION ALL
    -- etc
);

For that query, you'd need want an index on id on all tables, and for schema.data_2015 you should make it clustered (is it a primary key?).
If you would have designed your table correctly then it would all be in one and you could just do
SELECT id, col_1, col_2
FROM schema.data d
WHERE d.year = 2015
  AND d.id in (
    SELECT d2.id
    FROM schema.data
    WHERE d2.year >= 2016
);

For this you would want two indexes (year, id) and (id).

Adding to the classic list of "fallacies of distributed computing", I'd add "tables are designed correctly so that every query that will ever be run against them run efficiently". Which is to say that sometimes you don't get to make the rules and have to make due with what you've got.

@BenThul That's not a computing fallacy, that's a political and business fallacy (if it even exists).

One way to approach this would be to use multiple "exists" like this:
SELECT id, col_1, col_2
FROM SCHEMA.data_2015 d
WHERE d.year = 2015
    AND (
        EXISTS (
            SELECT NULL
            FROM SCHEMA.data_2016 d2016
            WHERE d.id = d2016.id
                AND d2016.year = 2016 -- nb: this line might be redundant
            )
        OR EXISTS (
            SELECT NULL
            FROM SCHEMA.data_2017 d2017
            WHERE d.id = d2017.id
                AND d2017.year = 2017 -- nb: this line might be redundant
            )
    -- OR EXISTS (....) -- one per needed year
        )

Whilst I'm not an R coder perhaps you could iterate to build the query itself, thereby running the query once and avoiding iteration with any data.
nb: I'm not sure if each of the sub-queries actually needs a predicate like and year = 2016 or and year >= 2016.  If the 2016 table has any ID that exists in the 2015 table then I assume the year stored against that ID of the 2016 table would be greater than 2015. Hence it may be possible to avoid these predicates and this would make the overall query simpler and faster. Consider this dbfiddle as an example of my reasoning - but it does depend on the data, so my assumption may be wrong.
